# Can we export graphical data to pdf using php scripts?

Tags: php

Can we export graphical data to pdf using php scripts?
Suppose the graphs are rendered by flash and html css ,  can we export these graphical data to a pdf.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: images can be put to pdf. graph can be put as a image

Comment: can we convert html css generated graphs to image uisng php or javascript ?

Comment: check for htmltopdf library I think they provide this feature you have to write the html and they generate pdf based on what html you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i'm using the Open flash chart library 
http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/

and I found that we can save these flash charts into images..Amazing..
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation of your pdf library that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but it looks like exactly what you need. I doubt it does flash though. I would consider using svg, canvas or imaes for graphs.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/